# Logstash does not transmit logs from file to elastic

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have logstash config work with `6.5.1` version but not work with `6.5.3`

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:\gitProjects\my\sources\my.log"
        codec => "json"
        type => "my"
    }
}

output {
    if [type]=="my" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "my-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

1) I start `elasticksearch` and open `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` - I see empty page

2) I start `kibana`  and open `http://localhost:5601` after that I see

```
health status index     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana_1 DeLeJPxsR02cAPdCCHsVrg   1   0          4            0     22.6kb         22.6kb
```

in `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`

3) I start my app and I have my.log with data

4) I start `Logstash` - `logstash.bat -f my.conf` and it start success:

```
[2018-12-19T14:55:27,550][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started
 Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

But Have not new indexies in elastic. I do not understand why. either he doesn’t see the file with the logs or cannot write to the elastic or I forget to do something

Comment: can you include entire logstash logs after you start  the server?

Comment: did not quite understand your question

Comment: For testing purposes, it could be interesting to add a stdout output, that way you'll be able to narrow down the issue: no output = the issue is with logstash/before logstash; with output = the issue is with elasticseach

Comment: Is logstash able to read the logs in your file? In case the logs are being read they would get printed alongside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for me(Windows).You might want to give this a try

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/gitProjects/my/sources/my.log"   # Use / instead of \
        codec => "json"
        type => "my"  
        start_position => "beginning"  # Add these two lines to your code
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}

output {
    if [type]=="my" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "my-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

For more info you can refer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files

Comment: Yes Thank you very much! the problem was really `/`